# Connect to SQL Server Server with SSL from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, ssl

How do I connect to a SQL Server with SSL from PHP?

**Edit**
I should be more elaborate on this. We have a php-mysql application. We need to save data on a SQL Server also. Initially we were using mssql_connect('server', 'db_user', 'db_pwd')
to connect to the remote SQL server. but now we need to send it over ssl.

We would like to use the existing ssl cert already on server (currently used by site on IIS as ssl cert) to make it so we can connect to SQL Server with  secure connection.

Comment: I am having the same issue. My site is hosted on php/mysql platform and I too need to update data on mssql. And I have already mentioned **"mssql.secure_connection = ON"** in my php.ini and the phpinfo is showing this enabled, but when I try to make connection to my mssql server 2008 using **mssql_connect("server:port","username","password")** an error arises that **"Unable to connect to server: servername:port"**. I am using freeTDS.

Answer (score 3):

What have you tried already ?

[`mssql_connect()`](http://php.net/mssql_connect) should work out for you.

Since you provided no error I'm guessing: `"Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to: OURSERVER.local in ...."` ?

Have you set the mssql.secure_connection ini option to true?

Answer (score 2):

mssql_connect can use secured connection if php is configured ...

go into the php.ini and verify the mssql.secure_connection parameter :

```
[MSSQL]
mssql.secure_connection = On
```

Comment: Do you use Apache or IIS with PHP ?

Comment: i think that iis use the windows ssl certs and for apache i'm not sure.